# Requirement change: Use database table instead of enums. How to deal with existing records that use enum value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql, enums

So requirements (actually the law) have changed, and the client wants to be able to add/remove values from what is currently an enum. So I need to create a database table instead that allows the client to dynamically deal with the list of values at runtime.

Currently there is a table in my database called `tblJob`, this table has a column `PaymentTypes` of type `int` which corresponds to the enum that has been used. So every time a new job is created in the system, the user selects a PaymentType from this enum list, and it is stored as a new record in `tblJob`

To deal with the new requirements, I have added a new table `tblPaymentTypes`, and hardcoded the current enum list into the table. Each value here has a unique `GUID` identifier. That's all good.

Now, for each new job, the `PaymentType` options are retrieved from the database and the user selects one. However, I need to change the **type** of the column `PaymentTypes` in the table `tblJob` to allow for `GUID` values instead of integers.

I could do this but what about all the existing records who all have a integer value as the `PaymentType` ?

From MSDN on modifying column types with existing data in them:

> Modifying the data type of a column that already contains data can result in the permanent loss of data when the existing data is converted to the new type. In addition, code and applications that depend on the modified column may fail. These include queries, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, and client applications. Note that these failures will cascade. For example, a stored procedure that calls a user-defined function that depends on the modified column may fail. Carefully consider any changes you want to make to a column before making it.

Which makes perfect sense.

To avoid this question being too localized, these are the general questions I'm asking:

- How do I deal with existing records when changing the column type? Do I have to write a one-time script that maps the current value into the new `GUID` value.
- Is the usage of a database table to replace the enum, even the correct choice in this situation? Is there any concept of a dynamic enum in C#?

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do the identifiers need to be GUIDs?  If the lookup table simply uses integer identifiers (as most tables generally do) then the initial population of records in that table can line up exactly with the enum's integer values.  Then no data migration is necessary, simply add the foreign key relationship from `tblJob` to `tblPaymentTypes` and you're done.

If you *must* use GUIDs (though I still contend that you shouldn't, if for no other reason than they make terrible clustered indexes) then you're going to have a data migration process which will likely consist of these steps:

1. Add the `tblPaymentTypes` table and data.
2. Add a GUID column to `tblJob`, nullable, no foreign key.
3. Update `tblJob` to set every value of the new column to the corresponding value from the enum (likely a hard-coded mapping because it's a one-time script).
4. Make the new column non-nullable and a foreign key to `tblPaymentTypes`.
5. Drop the column from `tblJob` which contained the integer enum values.
6. Update consuming code to use the new column instead of the old column.

Actually executing these steps should be pretty quick if it's all planned and scripted ahead of time, you'll likely just have a moment or two of downtime in the process.  (You'll want to isolate the database from the application when migrating data like this to avoid any kind of data corruption from any mid-migration state change.)  But you can see how it would be a *lot* easier to just use the same data type you already have.

Comment: Thank you. It was my initial intention to simply use the existing numerical values as IDs. To simplify the question, I said that I created the tblPaymentTypes table, but it actually already exists with GUID as identifiers. The existing records are used another place in the system but are still PaymentTypes. I added my hardcoded values to the table, generating new GUID values for the identifiers. That's why I tried to think about using the existing GUID values.

Your answer got me thinking. Do you think I should add a new column to tblPaymentTypes, naming it e.g. enumMappingId of type int?

Comment: Or go with your steps of using the GUIDs ?

Comment: @user1070241: I don't think you should keep around mappings forever as vestiges of code that no longer exists, no.  Having two identifiers for something is just asking for unnecessary complexity.  But I do think the identifiers should probably have been integers in the first place.  If changing the identifiers to integers is out of the question, then the only other option is to change the consuming identifiers (in this case the foreign key in `tblJob`) to match the identifiers (in this case the GUIDs).

Comment: Ok. But as the client will be able to dynamically add/delete values from the list, won't this quickly corrupt the mapping? Say I change the id to int in tblPaymentTypes and then the 5th record is deleted by the client. Will the IDs decrement? Or what happens in that case?

Comment: @user1070241: IDs should never change.  What you're asking is a question for business logic... Should the users even be able to "delete" a lookup record which is currently in use by data records?  If not, then they need to modify existing records before deleting it.  If so, then it needs to be a "soft delete" which means they merely "deactivate" it in some way but never actually remove the record from the table.  One thing you *definitely* don't want to do is delete a lookup record and leave orphaned data records which depend on it.

Comment: You are right. I need to think a bit more about this. Thank you for your input. I'll definitely be using it.